# How to rewind and look at previous offset in a partition using Kafka Go client's Consumer

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka. Currently I am experimenting with this [Channel Consumer example](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/tree/9f5af4225f71044489783d9726429e8d911304f0/examples/consumer_channel_example) from Confluent Inc's Github repo

From what I know, consumers are separated into groups. Each group has their own offset in the partition. Let's say I have 40 messages in a particular topic let's call it, owner_commands. A consumer, belongs to the dog group, joins and begins to consume those 40 messages.

When I disconnected and reconnected this consumer, I noticed that messages don't show up anymore. It says that I have reached the end of file. However, if I join the cluster with another consumer, which belongs to a different group (say cat) I get to read those 40 messages again.

Do you know if there is a way for consumers in the dog group to rewind and replay those messages again using Kafka's Go API. I looked at the source code for Kafka Golang API, I couldn't find anything that indicates to me that I can rewind and look at a particular message in the past.

Thank you

Comment: You may want to check https://github.com/Shopify/sarama which is a popular library for kafka - it does allow you to specify the specific offset you wish to read from, or accept 'Oldest' as the start point, or 'Newest'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CommitOffsets and just commit back to the offset you want to rewind to. The next poll will start from that offset.

CommitOffsets is documented here:
http://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-go/index.html#Consumer.CommitOffsets

Outside of the API, there's functionality in the kafka-consumer-groups command to move the position of consumer groups as well. This is released with Apache Kafka 0.11.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I have a better understanding of how Kafka works. I just realized that I have to set enable.auto.commit to false to make it work. Using my previous example, for my dog group, I perform a commit on owner_commands[0]@0 and when I disconnect my consumer and reconnect it, all the messages from [0]@0 to the most recent ones are replayed!!! 

However, I want to know more about the command to move the position of consumer group. Why is it outside of the API? How can I get access to that?

Comment: The kafka-consumer-groups command is executed by a shell script and comes with the Kafka package. You can find it in the bin directory. It's more like a broker side operation so it's not in the API. It actually uses the Java consumer API to do its thing under the covers.

Comment: Is there a way to do the equivalent of the kafka-consumer-groups command using the api? I'm working on a kafka library that multiple clients will be calling, and we'd like them to be able to reset their offsets to the earliest for a particular topic and group.

Comment: Yeah you can hit the Kafka Admin API on the broker to do this if you need to do it from outside the consumer.